# SQL query returning wrong century when joined with another table

Tags: sql, oracle12c, aix

I have a table with all variations of dates. For which a table can be joined to or have more details on that specific time frame, fiscal year,fiscal quarter, etc. when the order was established. However, when I am joining this to a table, with a table we will call SALES, it is returning the wrong century.

When the table is joined based on its "Sale date" done in the format DD-MM-YY, it is joining its value of "sale date" for example, 05-JUN-55, to the date table. When this join happens, It is pulling back the calendar year of 2055 not 1955 as desired.

The  join in questions is:

```
WHERE (1                                            =1)
AND (SALES.SALE_DATE                       = DATES.CALENDAR_DATE (+))
```

The date table has ranges from 1800s-2100s. Meaning there are multiple 05-Jun-55s
(1855,1955,2055....)
[Sample snippet of how the DATE table is structured.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjMm6.png)

I have tried searching to see if it is the date setup for the DB. We have oracle 12c running on ASM.

Current NLS parameters are set as following:

```
NAME                    TYPE   VALUE    
----------------------- ------ -------- 
nls_calendar            string          
nls_comp                string BINARY   
nls_currency            string          
nls_date_format         string          
nls_date_language       string          
nls_dual_currency       string          
nls_iso_currency        string          
nls_language            string AMERICAN 
nls_length_semantics    string BYTE     
nls_nchar_conv_excp     string FALSE    
nls_numeric_characters  string          
nls_sort                string          
nls_territory           string AMERICA  
nls_time_format         string          
nls_time_tz_format      string          
nls_timestamp_format    string          
nls_timestamp_tz_format string
```

Adding [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjAGm.png) of where it returns the correct result in one of our environments. The date in question is in the red box. Jan 1st,2040. Which is incorrect.

Adding [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vywWw.png) of where it returns the incorrect result in one of our environments. The date in question is in the red box. Jan 1st,1940

More information can be provided if it would be beneficial.

Comment: Please provide sample data in text form along with your attempt and expected results

Comment: You could quote the problematic SQL statement, especially the join part. Eg: .`tab1 JOIN tab2 ON TO_CHAR(tab1.datefld)=TO_CHAR(tab2.datefld)`

Comment: If there are only two digits for a year, how do you know which century it belongs to? Unless you sort it out, you might be spending *ages* before you manage to join data properly.

Comment: Right, @Littlefoot. I thought the same thing. However I was not there for the design process. why their date table doesn't just start from when they started having records is beyond me. But either way, its currently DD-MM-YY not DD-MM-YYYY. 

Their queries is created by an ETL process using ODI. There is some flexibility with adjusting the query if I have that option.

Comment: This SALE_DATE is a string with a two-digit year? Wow, this is dumb.  The default date format might be `DD-MM-RR` vs `DD-MM-YY`, check `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: Wise man once said, in Oracle ALWAYS FORMAT DATES. 9/10 times this is the problem if you see funny dates.

Comment: Both columns in question are DATE format columns. 
SALES.SALE_DATE  (date)
and DATES.CALENDAR_DATE (date)